# REST api needs to be modified in order to allow be filtered?

Tags: rest, get, api-design

I'm developing an Xamarin App that gets its data from a REST API in Azure  connected to a BD in Azure.

I require that the data from one of the tables be filtered by one of the columns. I have tried to filter passing parameters in the URI like this:

```
GET /companies?category=banking&location=india
```

but even though the response is 200, it returns all the records and not the filtered data that I need.

I'm very new to this, so I don't know if I have to make changes in the REST API to allow to be filtered. Can you give me an example about how modify the GET controller for this table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this. Most API's will by default ignore any query parameters you send it, so it makes sense that the ones you added don't do anything.

If you control the API and you can modify the API, to add filtering support to your API you need to share the code that serves the API and possibly consult the documentation.

If you want filter from the client but don't have control of the server, there is nothing really you can do if the server doesn't already support this.